# Set the memory high and then set_time_limit to 0

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, php

In PHP if I set the the memory 100M via `ini_set` and then I set `set_time_limit(0);` Does that mean that my PHP memory allocation is 100M forever(Until I restart my Apache)?

Comment: ini_set is a function to set php configuration variables, you need to tell us what configuration variable are you setting 100M to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its reset back to the original at the end of script execution.

[From the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

> string ini_set ( string $varname , string $newvalue )
>
> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration
>   option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and
>   will be restored at the script's ending.

and `set_time_limit(0);` is treated the same.

Example:

```
// 1. Script starts
echo ini_get('memory_limit');//128M

// 2. We set a new limit the script will now have 100M
ini_set('memory_limit','100M');
echo ini_get('memory_limit'); //100M

die;
// 3. Script ends now its set back to 128M
```

With `set_time_limit(0);` it just tells the script to not time out, tho say you were to use `set_time_limit(0);` within a loop then on each iteration its internal counter is set to 0 over and over.

So if you were to use `set_time_limit(1);` within a loop as long as each iteration of the loop did not last longer then 1 second then it would still not time out as `set_time_limit(n);` would reset the internal timeout counter to 0 on each iteration.

Example of it not timing out after 1 second:

```
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++){
    set_time_limit(1);
    usleep(999998); //2micro seconds from a second
    echo $i;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, somehow my localhost stays at 100M for my next script execution and every time script increases 100M on top of the last increment.